# Sort From Nested Object Array MongoDB - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hope you are doing well and Happy New Year to everybody. Hope it will end up better than 2020 X). I am facing an issue here that I can not find a solution so far. Here is a data MongoDB model example :

```
`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe715bf43c3ca0009503f1d"), 
"firstname" : "Nicolas ",
"lastname" : "Mazzoleni",
"email" : "nicolas.mazzoleni@orange.fr",
"items" : [ 
    {
        "item" : ObjectId("5f6c5422eeaa1364b0d7b267"),
        "createdAt" : "2020-12-26T10:51:43.685Z"
    }, 
    {
        "item" : ObjectId("5f6c5422eeaa1364b0d7b270"),
        "createdAt" : "2021-01-04T09:21:46.260Z"
    }
],
"createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-26T10:51:43.686Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-04T09:21:46.260Z"),
"__v" : 0
}`
```

Let's assume that I have a lot of rows like this one above, with different 'items.createdAt' dates.

At the end, the goal is to do a query that would find an item where the ObjectId is equal to what I am looking for, and sort by the matching 'items.createdAt' date. Here is the query I use at the moment that is not sorting by the matching nested object :

```
  `const items = await repo
  .find({ 'items.item': ObjectId("5f6c5422eeaa1364b0d7b270") })
  .sort({ 'items.createdAt': -1 })
  .limit(5)`
```

PS : I also tried to use aggregations that ended up with this query

```
  `const items = await repo.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$items' },
  { $match: { 'items.item': ObjectId("5f6c5422eeaa1364b0d7b270") } },
  { $sort: { 'items.createdAt': -1 } },
  { $limit: 5 },
])`
```

This one is working like a charm, but it does not use indexes, and I am searching into millions of records, which makes this query way to long to execute.

Thank you for all your help ! Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, MongoDB can't sort nested array by simple Query. You need to use aggregate for that.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "items.item": ObjectId("5f6c5422eeaa1364b0d7b270")
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
        "items.createdAt": -1
     }
  },
  { "$limit" : 5 },
  {
    "$group": {
        "items": {
            "$push": "$items"
        },
        "_id": 1
  }
])
```

Comment: Hey @JustRaman,

Thanks for the quick answer. So if aggregate is the only solution, would you have a way to make this query using indexes ? Because the database behind contains millions of record. Thanks 

Comment: Aggregate will use any indexes if exists there is no special way. other than this.